# Error de instalación de librería caret de r

Tags: r, packages, libreria

E intentado varias cositas pero no me han funcionado, ayuda por favor!

> library("caret")
> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘caret’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
> namespace ‘cli’ 3.3.0 is already loaded, but >= 3.4.0 is required

Answer (score 0):

El error dice que la versión de cli es 3.3.0 pero que requiere una versión igual o mayor a 3.4.0, solamente instala cli otra vez.

```
install.packages("cli")
```

[CRAN - Package cli](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cli/index.html)

[Repositorio de r-lib/cli](https://github.com/r-lib/cli)

Comment: Luego de instalar cli, sigo teniendo el mismo incidente 

> library(caret)
Loading required package: ggplot2
Loading required package: lattice
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘caret’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
 namespace ‘cli’ 3.3.0 is already loaded, but >= 3.4.0 is required

Comment: Es el mismo error, ahora instala ggplot2.